# How to remove slash and .html from links in htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a lot of folders, each with index.html

```
/folder1/index.html
/folder2/index.html
/folder3/index.html
```

Links are available at /folder1/, /folder2/, /folder3/

How i can remove last slash? for /folder1, /folder2, /folder3

Comment: Welcome to SO, could you please post sample of URLs like from which URL to which URL you need for better understanding of your question.

Comment: Hi. thanks. https://example.com/folder1/index.html to https://example.com/folder1

Answer (score 1):

***EDIT:*** Since OP is NOT clear if OP wants to remove slashes for only URLs which have `index.html` files or for any kind of URL, so adding this solution to handle this scenario with any kind of url here.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

---

---

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} .*/index\.html/?$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.html/? /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

Comment: @Venfor, could you please clear your browser cache, I have tested this and it worked fine for me(even it removes index file name for me when I test it), please check it and let me know how it goes then?

Comment: https://automir24.com.ua/toyota , not work. i have slash after folder name

Comment: @Venfor, I have tested url for example `http://localhost/test/index.html/` and it removes `/` from it. Do you NOT have index.html files all the time in your url? Because this url will work for only index.html files, let me know(its as per your shown samples only).

Comment: @Venfor, Please clear your browser cache and try in new browser window my EDIT solution and let me know then?

Comment: ye but i need not `http://localhost/test/index.html/` i need `http://localhost/test`

Comment: @Venfor, then my first solution itself working for your previous comment(`http://localhost/test/index.html/` example please clear your browser cache and check), it removes `index.html` from url. Do you have any other file apart from `index.html` in url or it can be anything else also? Please clarify.

Comment: I need to remove not only index.html, i need to remove index.html and previous slash

Comment: ```RewriteEngine On
DirectorySlash Off
RewriteRule ^toyota$ /toyota/index.html [L,E=LOOP:1]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.html [NC,L]```

Comment: thats works but, i need to write folder name ( `RewriteRule ^toyota$ /toyota/index.html [L,E=LOOP:1]`

Comment: @Venfor, sorry I didn't get where you need to write folder name, please give clear examples by showing urls.